# Powershell: How to Validate Range between 1 to 15 and it should accepts pattern as 1,2,3,4,5 to 15

Tags: regex, powershell

I am a newbie in Power Shell Scripting.
I am trying to Achieve a functionality, that should accepts inputs from user in below criteria

1. Only Digits
2. Range Between 1 to 15
3. Should accept String of Array with comma Separated values ex: 1,2,3,4,14,15
4. Can Contain space in between commas
5. Values should not be duplicated
6. The Returned values must be Array

Till now, I have tried

```
Function Validate-Choice{
[cmdletbinding()]
Param(
[Parameter(Position=0,Mandatory=$True)]
[ValidateRange(1,15)]
[string[]]$Item
)
Process {$Item}
}
Validate-Choice 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,13 # Similar Way i want O/p

Out Put: 
     1
     2
     3
     4
     5
     6
     7
     8
     9
     10
     11
     13


 $ReadInput = Read-Host  -prompt "Please Choose from the list [1/2/3/4/5/6/7/8/9/10/11/12/13/14] You can select multiple Values  EX: 1, 2, 3 --  "
 $userchoices = Validate-Choice -item $ReadInput
 $userchoices

If read the same input from Host Getting Below Error

Validate-Choice : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Item'. The argument    cannot be validated because 
its type "String" is not the same type (Int32) as the maximum and minimum limits of the parameter. Make sure the argument is of type Int32 and then try  the command again. At line:10 char:21
+     Validate-Choice '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,13'
+                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Validate-Choice],   ParameterBindingValidationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Validate-Choice
```

And  also i am trying with different Regex patterns. But failing

```
Function Test-Something {
[cmdletbinding()]
Param(
    [Parameter(Position=0,Mandatory=$True)]
    [ValidatePattern('(?:\s*\d{1,15}[1-15]\s*(?:,|$))+$')]
    [string[]]$Item
)
Process { $Item }
}
```

The above functions are partially resulting.
Can any one please help me here..!?

Comment: `\d{1,15}` says a number between 1 and 15 digits long. `[1-15]` is not the numbers 1-15 you could do `([1-9]|1[0-5])`. The `[]` are character classes along for specific characters or ranges of single characters. For example `a-z` is valid for lowercase alpha characters and `0-9` is valid for numbers 0 through 9. For `9` and higher you need to add a `+` or add in conditionals (also for decimals).

Comment: Thanks..! Chris85. Could you pls provide the full regex pattern to do that?

Comment: I don't have powershell so I can't test. I could write up a regex that I think would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would probably be easiest if you just changed the parameter type to `[int[]]` then your ValidateRange attribute does most of the work.  It doesn't handle duplicates though.  Turns out you can't use [ValidateScript()] as @PetSerAl points out.  So that leaves checking the parameter the old fashioned way, in a begin block:

```
Function Test-Something {
    [cmdletbinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Position=0, Mandatory)]
        [ValidateRange(1, 15)]
        [int[]]$Item
    )

    Begin {
        $ht = @{}
        foreach ($i in $Item) {
            if ($ht.ContainsKey("$i")) {
                throw "Parameter Item must contain unique values - duplicate '$i'"
            } 
            else {
                $ht["$i"] = $i
            }
        }
    }

    Process { 
        [string]$Item 
    }
}

Test-Something (1,2,3,4,3)
```

Note that this won't work if you make the Item parameter accept pipeline input.  In the pipeline input case, $Item will not be set in the `begin` block.

Comment: Thanks Keith Hill..! But can we pass inputs like 1,2,3,5... ,15? If i pass 1 to 15. This will loop to 15 times right. Can we create more reliable snippet which will satisfies the performance as well?

Comment: If your range is really 1 to 15 I don't think the perf of ValidateScript would be that bad.  Now if the range was 1..10000 then yeah, perf could be an issue.

Comment: `ValidateScript` run script for each element of collection instead of collection itself, so you can not check duplicates this way.

Comment: @KeithHill,  that function is working. I am using like this ` $ReadInput = (Read-Host  -prompt "Please Choose etc...") -split ','
$userchoices = Test-Something -item $ReadInput
$userchoices.split(" ") `

Comment: @KeithHill,  but the $userchoices returing previous set of results whenever i pass wrong input data & the PS throwing error.

Comment: @KeithHill - i am using $userchoices  = $null as 1st line in my code. Now Getting the o/p as expected.!   Thanks..!

Answer (score 0):

Naren_Ch

Your 1st usage of the advanced function (AF)

```
Validate-Choice 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,13 # Similar Way i want O/p
```

is correct - you are inputting data as expected by the AF.

Now, look at the example reading the input from the host:

```
$ReadInput = Read-Host  -prompt "Please Choose from the list [1/2/3/4/5/6/7/8/9/10/11/12/13/14] You can select multiple Values  EX: 1, 2, 3 --  "
```

When you do this, `$ReadInput` is a string, and in this case, it's a string full of commas!
Consequently, your data inputted to the AF will result in error caused by validation code, written by yourself.

To correct the situation, just do this:

```
$ReadInput = (Read-Host  -prompt "Please Choose etc...") -split ','
$userchoices = Validate-Choice -item $ReadInput
```

You must remember that data read by `Read-Host` is a string (just 1 string).